# Control creation in .designer.cs

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have some user controls in our app that refer back to the form they're sitting on to get some initialisation values. Depending on the form they're on different behaviours are needed.

So the user controls catch OnLoad and ParentChanged events, and you FindForm to gain access to the form they're sat on... and all has been good for a couple of years.

However, last week we started to have problems with some controls not initialising properly, and after much searching I can see that what's happening is that if the controls are sat on a container rather than directly on the form, then when the ParentChanged event of the control fires, it could be that the container is not yet added to the form and so FindForm does not work.

The odd thing is that this has only just started happening, and it seems that since we upgraded to the latest VS, when a form is saved after editing, the designer is massively changing the order in which controls are created and sometimes this causes a fail.

Does anyone know if/why the VS designer behaviour has changed?   And also, if there is anyway to control the create order of form controls in the designer file?

I can manually edit the designer file to fix, but on a resave, VS puts it back the way it wants again.

Comment: it has always been risky to rely on anything the VS tools or the runtime does with auto-generated files. whatever the answer will be, what if it changes again? could you relocate the calls to parent form dependending code to a later stage of the lifecycle, as form_load? can be somthing as simple as foreach control ... control.visitparent(this)...

Comment: The very first lines of the `...Designer.cs` says: "Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is regenerated." You need to rethink your design.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Not necessarily; my answer below was literally just generated, and only included a message above the InitializeComponent method.

Comment: Post the code from `ParentChanged` and `FindForm` so we may look into it.

Comment: You don't need FindForm.  UserControls have a ParentForm property.  Having it depend on other controls on the form is a design flaw.

Comment: @Marisa I just google `github Designer.cs` and used the first link. While it is worded differently the message is the same.

Comment: I don't think that OP is talking about manually changing the designer.cs file. It is something that _in its main code_ depends on the order of creation of the controls. This is very risky because none guarantees that the order will be always the same. We should see that code to understand what happens and suggest some workaround if any exists

Answer (score -1):

So while this might have worked for you for some time, the core problem lies in the handy message included in every Designer.cs file.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
  /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
  /// </summary>
```

In reality this message should really apply to anything in the Designer.cs file. I would gently suggest that you should take a hard look at your code and why you're doing what you're doing, and change it as soon as possible to not rely on Designer.cs file modifications.